# SQL Server: Importing and archiving weekly data

Tags: sql-server, import, archive

***Any ideas/suggestions appreciated....***

I've been asked to come up with a simple way to import new data we receive from an outside vendor (text files). We get several text files and each needs to be imported into its own table. Some tables have to have the current/existing data moved into a table called `TABLENAME_Previous` (to work with various existing reports), then have the current table emptied out and the new data imported into it. Also, any data now in the "previous" table has to be appended to an archive table.

Here's an example:

`customer.txt` comes in from vendor....

1. First we move the contents of `customers_previous` to `customers_arch`
2. Next we move the contents of `customers` to `customers_previous`
3. Finally we import the new `customers.txt` file into the table `customers`

Has anyone ever written a SQL routine to do this, or knows where to find one, that wouldn't be too painful to modify?

Thanks

Comment: Is the customer.txt file delimited or fixed? Sample data of the text file would help too.

Comment: comma delimited CSV
we actually have 12 different text files, with anywhere from 10 to 50 fields each, so it would be a pain to post their contents all here

Comment: Are the text files names consistent each week? And all tables are textfilename_previous to textfilename_arch, etc? If names are consistent, then SSIS should be able to handle this.

Comment: Yes, they are consistent (fortunately!)

Comment: I have never used SSIS, can you point me to a resource to find a way to do this?

Comment: Try here... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this:

To copy your previous data to Archive

```
Insert into customers_arch select * from customers_previous
```

To Copy your Customer Data to Previous:

```
truncate table customers_previous;
insert into customers_previous select * from customers
```

Then to Load you text file use Bulk Insert to load your customer table after clearing it.

```
truncate table customers;
bulk    insert customers
from    'd:\yourfolder\customers.txt'
WITH   
      (  
         FIELDTERMINATOR =',',  
         ROWTERMINATOR ='\n'  
      );
```

**UPDATE:**
Ok, Brian, to answer your other question, How to run it for multiple files saved in your WeeklyTable.

Suppose your WeeklyTable is like this:

```
Declare @WeeklyTable TABLE(ID int Identity(1,1), [FileName] varchar(50))
insert into @WeeklyTable Values
('Customers'),('Orders'), ('Order_Details')
```

You can create a dynamic query to run your script for each file.

```
Declare @Template varchar(max)
Set @Template = '
    -- Start of [[FILENAME]] --------------------
    Insert into [FILENAME]_arch select * from [FILENAME]_previous
    GO

    truncate table [FILENAME]_previous;
    insert into [FILENAME]_previous select * from [FILENAME]
    GO

    truncate table [FILENAME];
    bulk    insert [FILENAME]
    from    ''d:\yourfolder\[FILENAME].txt''
    WITH   
          (  
             FIELDTERMINATOR ='','',  
             ROWTERMINATOR =''\n''  
          );


'
Declare @s varchar(max)
Declare @FileName varchar(50)
Declare @ID int =0

Select TOP 1 @ID=ID, @FileName=[FileName] From @WeeklyTable Where ID>@ID order by ID
While @@ROWCOUNT>0 Begin
    Set @s = REPLACE(@Template, '[FILENAME]', @FileName)
    Print @s
--  EXEC(@s)  -- Uncomment to EXEC the script.
    Select TOP 1 @ID=ID, @FileName=[FileName] From @WeeklyTable Where ID>@ID order by ID
End
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try...looks pretty straightforward!

Comment: Another question...how could I write this to do it for each of several tables, which I have in a table called

Comment: How could I run that for each of the tables named in a table called 

SELECT [FileName]
      ,[FileAfterRename]
      ,[TableName]

Comment: Darn, I keep accidentally adding new unfinished comments...ARGH!
  
Anyway...

How can I run this for each table in a table called WeeklyFiles with a field called FieldName

Comment: @BrianBattles, please see the updated code, to use for multiple files saved in your WeeklyFiles.

Comment: What is the ID field and variable in your sample code?

Comment: That looks like it will work great, thanks for the help Ahmed!

Comment: @BrianBattles the ID is just to control the loop in order to retrieve the file names one by one.