# Inserting localserver database tables records into host server corresponds database tables records

Tags: sql-server, database

i have connected with my local server to host server through linked servers.

I have Database AA1 and the related tables aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4 on the local server and also I have Database AA2 and the related tables aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4 on the host server.

There are 50 records in each local server database AA1 tables and
thousands of records into each host server databse AA2 tables.

Now i want to insert all of my local server database AA1 tables records into corresponding host server database AA2 tables. So that after inserting all tables data on the host server database,the host sever database AA2, disappears all of it's thousand records in aa1,aa2,aa3,aa4 tables and only have my local server database AA1 data into corresponds tables.

help me with SQL Server Query.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Please some one help me with suitable answer

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to replace your remote tables with your local tables.if that is the case, truncate the tables on the remote server, then insert the local tables into the remote tables.

To truncate the tables, you may use:

```
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE aa2.dbo.aa1') AT [LINKEDSERVER]
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE aa2.dbo.aa2') AT [LINKEDSERVER]
EXEC ('TRUNCATE TABLE aa2.dbo.aa3') AT [LINKEDSERVER]
```

Then, to insert your local records into the remote server.

```
INSERT INTO [LINKEDSERVER].aa2.dbo.aa1 
SELECT * FROM aa1.dbo.aa1

INSERT INTO [LINKEDSERVER].aa2.dbo.aa2
SELECT * FROM aa1.dbo.aa2

INSERT INTO [LINKEDSERVER].aa2.dbo.aa3
SELECT * FROM aa1.dbo.aa3
```

Comment: is this possible without truncate or delete...?

Comment: If you want to keep the data on the remote host, then don't execute the Truncate part and just execute the insert statements.

Comment: i want to replace all data of remote server into locel server data

Comment: it will take much time because i have more than hundred tables on both servers and i need to replace all these tables data

Comment: is there any other query of sql rather than truncate or delete...?

Comment: Probably, I didn't understand your requirements. Can you please show  contents of one table of your Local, Remote and the expected result.

Comment: You could try with [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) if you insist you don't want to delete/truncate.

Comment: @Ahmed Saeed there are same database tables on remote and local server and there are thousands of tables into both side databases and i want to replace all of remote server data into local server data, If i use truncate and insert query for all thousands of tables. the query will be very large and also time consuming. so that i want a query which would short and time saving. is there any other way to solve it...?

Comment: I guess the Truncate statement runs very quick. however, if you have thousands of tables, you can create one dynamic script where you pass the table name as parameter. please check my answer here where this user have table names stored in a table and he want to weekly archive them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40089552/sql-server-importing-and-archiving-weekly-data/40090012?noredirect=1#comment67595988_40090012

Comment: Thanks #Ahmed Saeed, #TT & #TheGameIsWar for your time and helpful responses